# QGIS 3 lags and/or crashes

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, windows-10

QGIS crashes relatively often on my computer with Windows 10.

How can I research what is happening before the crash happens?

Better, it is not crashing with the dialog "ooops, qgis crashes" it lags with "no response in title" ... when then closing the app crashes resp. win says "closing anyway or wait" ...

Comment: What are you doing on your qgis ?
running scripts ? loading attribute tables ? huge shapefiles ? processing tools ?

Comment: Same for me on Debian, just closes with no warning or error. I think more often when using WMS and WMTS layers

Comment: I have a lot of vector layers. It happens in different situations, sometimes on moving / pan the map, sometimes wenn clicking to fast from one to another option oder layer or tool ... I can not find a special situation. As I said, QGIS does not disapers, it lags sometime for seconds or minutes, sometimes for hours ... and sometimes for nearly forever or until my patience is at the end.

Comment: can you add the contents of QGIS's help>about and window's System Information?

Comment: QGIS-Version
3.12.1-București
QGIS-Codeversion
121cc00ff0
Kompiliert gegen Qt
5.11.2
Laufendes Qt
5.11.2
Kompiliert mit GDAL/OGR
3.0.4
Läuft mit GDAL/OGR
3.0.4
Kompiliert mit GEOS
3.8.1-CAPI-1.13.3
Läuft mit GEOS
3.8.1-CAPI-1.13.3
Kompiliert mit SQLite
3.29.0
Läuft mit SQLite
3.29.0
PostgreSQL-Client-Version
11.5
SpatiaLite-Version
4.3.0
QWT-Version
6.1.3
QScintilla2-Version
2.10.8
Kompiliert mit PROJ
6.3.1
Läuft mit PROJ
Rel. 6.3.1, February 10th, 2020
BS-Version
Windows 10 (10.0)

Comment: Aktive Python-Erweiterungen
AnotherDXF2Shape; 
autoSaver; 
AzimuthDistanceCalculator; 
BackupLayer; 
batchvectorlayersaver; 
batch_gps_importer; 
BoundingBox; 
BulkVectorExport; 
ClipMultipleLayers; 
ale; 
ezprinter; 
gistools; 
GpxSegmentImporter; 
ImportPhotos; 
kmltools; 
latlontools; 
loadthemall; 
MapsPrinter; 
mmqgis; 
ORStools; 
OSMDownloader; 
parcel_plugin; 
pgRoutingLayer; 
pickLayer; 
pluginbuilder3; 
plugin_reloader;

Comment: PointConnector; 
QCopycanvas; 
qfieldsync; 
qgis2web; 
qgiscloud; 
QLocklayers; 
QRectangleCreator; 
QuickOSM; 
QuickPrint; 
quick_map_services; 
route_sqlite; 
SaxonyCadastralParcels; 
scriptrunner3; 
searchlayers; 
SelectByRelationship; 
send2google_earth; 
shapetools; 
snail; 
VectorBender; 
xyToPoint; 
zoomview; 
zoom_level; 
db_manager; 
MetaSearch; 
processing; 
CustomToolBar